# SQL Cumulative count on unique Ids

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have dataset like below (sorted by Time column):

```
Time        ID1        ID2
2:00:00 AM  41  A56E34E0-FBE5-4C58-BDBD-87112E73A978
3:00:00 AM  34  B129798B-485E-41BB-8B9C-39A0E1841109
4:00:00 AM  41  A56E34E0-FBE5-4C58-BDBD-87112E73A978
4:00:00 AM  41  C1C14D08-C155-4857-93E2-3A748AC95C8D
4:00:00 AM  34  A4D389B1-C38F-446A-9336-6AA193D8F0E0
4:00:00 AM  17  C1C14D08-C155-4857-93E2-3A748AC95C8D
```

I want to get cumulative counts of ID2 if it has not appeared before for same ID1 grouped by Time and ID1. So for above dataset intermediate result could be:

```
Time        ID1        ID2                                     IsNewForID1
2:00:00 AM  41  A56E34E0-FBE5-4C58-BDBD-87112E73A978        1
3:00:00 AM  34  B129798B-485E-41BB-8B9C-39A0E1841109        1
4:00:00 AM  41  A56E34E0-FBE5-4C58-BDBD-87112E73A978        0
4:00:00 AM  41  C1C14D08-C155-4857-93E2-3A748AC95C8D        1
4:00:00 AM  34  A4D389B1-C38F-446A-9336-6AA193D8F0E0        1
4:00:00 AM  17  C1C14D08-C155-4857-93E2-3A748AC95C8D        1
```

And Grouped by Time, ID1 would be:

```
Time        ID1       Count
2:00:00 AM  41  1
3:00:00 AM  34  1
4:00:00 AM  41  1
4:00:00 AM  34  1
4:00:00 AM  17  1
```

How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: Please tell us what **concrete database system** this is for - many things are vendor-specific. Are you using MySQL? Postgres? SQL Server? Oracle? IBM DB2? Something else entirely? Please update your tags to show what database system (and which version of it!) you're using - thanks!

Comment: If the last row's ID1 in your example was 41, would the count for that hour and ID1 be 2 or 1? (In other words, would ID2 be considered new for ID1 if its first appearance for the same ID1 was in the same hour?)

Comment: I wouldn't have such data since that would be a duplicate row of the 4th row. The data is already grouped by Time, ID1 and ID2. If in case, ID1 was for last row was 41, then the count for ID1 41 at 4 AM should still be 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first occurrence of the pair `id1` and `id2` along with the time, why not just use `group by`?  The following is standard SQL:

```
select min(time) as time, id1, id2, 1 as count
from dataset
group by id1, id2;
```

Comment: I don't want to find the first occurrence, I am counting the number of ID2s for each ID1 excluding those if ID2 has already occurred for that ID1.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [Gordon Linoff's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28589309/297408) as a starting point for this kind of solution:

```
SELECT
  d.Time,
  d.ID1,
  d.ID2,
  IsNewForID1 = CASE WHEN g.Time IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM
  YourDataset AS d
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      Time = MIN(Time),
      ID1,
      ID2,
    FROM
      YourDataset
    GROUP BY
      ID1,
      ID2
  ) AS g ON g.Time = d.Time AND g.ID1 = d.ID1 AND g.ID2 = d.ID2
;
```

That is, the derived table contains first, "new", occurrences of `ID2` per `ID1` and you join it back to the original dataset to use as a reference and mark each row respectively.

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later version, you could rewrite the above using a window MIN:

```
SELECT
  Time,
  ID1,
  ID2,
  IsNewForID1 = CASE Time
    WHEN MIN(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY ID1, ID2) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END
FROM
  YourDataset
;
```

The idea is same as before but no join or derived table is needed because the first occurrences are obtained alongside details and the `IsNewForID1` column is calculated in the same scope. This method may particularly be preferable if `YourDataset` is actually a query, because the first variation would likely evaluate `YourDataset` twice and with the second one you avoid that.

Obviously, to get the final results, you would take either query and further group it by `Time` and `ID1` to take `SUM(IsForNewID1)`:

```
SELECT
  Time,
  ID1,
  Count = SUM(IsNewForID1)
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      Time,
      ID1,
      ID2,
      IsNewForID1 = CASE Time
        WHEN MIN(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY ID1, ID2) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END
    FROM
      YourDataset
  ) AS s
;
```

Note, though, that if `IsNewForID1` is actually needed only to get the counts, you could use Gordon's idea in a different way to skip that intermediate step, like this:

```
SELECT
  Time,
  ID1,
  Count = COUNT(*)
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      Time = MIN(Time),
      ID1,
      ID2,
    FROM
      YourDataset
    GROUP BY
      ID1,
      ID2
  ) AS s
;
```

Essentially, the results would be identical regardless of whether you calculate them using `IsNewForID1` or without it. However, in terms of rows, there might be difference. The former method could potentially return rows with `Count = 0`. For instance, it would return the following if row #4 in your example was absent:

```
Time        ID1  Count
----------  ---  -----
2:00:00 AM  41   1
3:00:00 AM  34   1
4:00:00 AM  41   0
4:00:00 AM  34   1
4:00:00 AM  17   1
```

The last method would simply omit rows with counts of 0, and so there would be no result for `4:00:00 AM, 41` if we removed the fourth row from the example data.